# JQuery AJAX PUT, not working

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm sending a JQuery AJAX call as follows, to update a record in an ActiveRecord DB:

```
var url_out = '/users/' + args.item.id;
$.ajax({
  url: url_out,
  type: 'POST',
  method: 'PUT',
  data: args.item,
  success: function(dat) {
    alert("did it");
  }
```

In Users controller, I have this:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

So I need to pass the data that's in args.item, instead, as params[:user]. Can one pass named parameters using the AJAX call?

Comment: type (default: 'GET')
Type: String
The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Dom, thanks very much. Yes, I had seen that. It turns out that isn't the problem. The PUT approach is working the same as POST with method PUT, suggested by the other person as well. I'm editing it to show a new view of the problem - if you get a chance, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I know that Rails actually is simulating the http verbs by adding a hidden parameter _method with value "PUT" and the actual request is a POST (due to some browsers not supporting all the verbs")

SO, you can try to do a post and add a parameter _method: "PUT"

Comment: thanks very much. It turns out it is a different problem. I'll update the post.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to thank @Dom and @Eduard for the help. It turns out I needed to do something like this:

```
x_out = {};
x_out["first_name"] = args.item.first_name;
x_send = {};
x_send["user"] = x_out;
```

and that lets me pass the named parameter to the update method in the controller.